# How do I make a Grid panel be no taller than needed to contain its contents?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a two-column layout using CSS Grid.

I have

```
.left_1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.left_2 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
...

.right_1 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.right_2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}

...
```

and so on.  The top two grid elements contain only header tags for headers that label each column:

```
<div class="left_1"><h4>Left Header</h4></div>
....
<div class="right_1"><h4>Right Header</h4></div>
```

These grid panels end up being much taller than they need to be, so that the headers (vertically aligned in the middle) float way above the rest of the columns so that it's not immediately clear that they're supposed to be labels for those columns.  I've colored the background of the `<h4>` element to confirm that these are the normal size: just tall enough to contain the text of the headers.  It's the Grid layout itself that's making the panels too big.

I've tried adding `grid-template-rows: fit-content();` (various percentages), `grid-template-rows: auto;`, `height: auto;`, `height: 100%;`, `height: fit-content;`, and `display: inline-block;` to the class descriptors for `left_1` and `right_1`, but nothing changes the height of the Grid panels.

How do I make the Grid panels be no taller than necessary to contain their contents?  I'd like to avoid hard-coding an exact number of pixels.

**Edit:** Here's a full file that shows the problem:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style>
            .columns {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            column-gap: 10px;
            }

            .left_1 {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            }
            .left_2 {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 2;
            }

            .right_1 {
            grid-column: 2;
            grid-row: 1;
            }
            .right_2 {
            grid-column: 2;
            grid-row: 2;
            }

            h4 {
            background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="left_1"><h4>Left Header</h4></div>
                <select class="left_2" multiple="yes">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                    <option>Option 4</option>
                </select>

                <div class="right_1"><h4>Right Header</h4></div>
                <select class="right_2" multiple="yes">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                    <option>Option 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please. Can you put your containers, where you store your left_1 and right_1 and so on elemens. Or put full html file, or runnable code snippet to see what you are talking about.

Comment: @Jan I've added a full code sample to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hack, but since all you need is to display clearly that the headers are labels for the columns.
 just add:
 `margin-bottom: 0;`
 to your h4 block in the CSS file.

So instead of the one exists, change it to the one below:

```
h4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work best.  In fact, setting both `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to zero shrinks the Grid row to just the right height.  Thanks!

Comment: In fact, after looking closer, this isn't a hack, it's the correct answer.  The grid boxes *were* only as tall as needed, but they needed to include the headers' top and bottom margins, which weren't made visible by coloring the header background, so I didn't realize they were the problem.  Eliminating the margins fixes everything and is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .columns {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
            row-gap: 0;
            /*grid-template-rows: min-content min-content;*/
            column-gap: 10px;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .left_1 {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 1;
        }
        .left_2 {
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 2;
        }
        .right_1 {
            grid-column: 2;
            grid-row: 1;
        }
        .right_2 {
            grid-column: 2;
            grid-row: 2;
        }
        select {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: min-content;
        }
        h4 {
            background-color: yellow;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="my_class">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="left_1"><h4>Left Header</h4></div>
        <div class="left_2">
            <select class="" multiple="yes">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
                <option>Option 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="right_1"><h4>Right Header</h4></div>
        <div class="right_2">
            <select class="" multiple="yes">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
                <option>Option 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both of these suggestions cause the two columns to separate to the left and right sides of the window with an enormous gap in between them, and absolutely nothing changes about the vertical position of the <h4> headers in the top two cells.

Comment: @DarienMarks Do you want result like this? [link](https://ibb.co/KFBMW36) , or something like this, but without space in the bottom? [link](https://ibb.co/qMvNvxV)

Comment: I'm looking for something with the headers positioned like the 2nd link, but the option boxes like the 1st link (listed vertically)

Comment: @DarienMarks I've edited my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: That still has the headers floating way above the rest of the columns for me.  To be clear, the 'select' elements are not the issue.  They could be anything.  The issue is entirely that the grid panels containing the headers are too tall.

Comment: @DarienMarks I've added margin 0 to h4 header. Is that right?